# Normal subgroups, Group order, Automorphisms

Tags: group-theory

I am a beginner at Mathematica and have a few problems.

1. Find all normal subgroups of the Alternating Group A[4].
2. Find the order of a group Aut(U[8]).
3. Find the group Aut(S[3]).

I've been trying to solve these problems, but I don't really know how to do it. In second I wrote:

**G1 = Automorphisms[U[8]]**

**GroupOrder[G1]**

and Mathematica says

"GroupOrder::grp: "Groupoid[{1,3,5,7},Mod[#1\ #2,8]&] is not a valid group." "

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the guide/GroupTheory in the help system.  You will want to use AlternatingGroup[], SymmetricGroup[], GroupOrder[], GroupGenerators[] and you may find GroupMultiplicationTable[] and CayleyGraph[] helpful.